# Selecting a serialized value from MySQL with a REGEX

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have a serialized field called **details** in a MySQL DB that looks like this:

```
a:4:{s:9:"bootstrap";s:14:"Boostrap_3.3.x";s:7:"layouts";s:10:"Responsive";s:13:"preprocessors";s:0:"";s:8:"browsers";s:117:"Latest_Chrome,Latest_Firefox,Latest_Safari,Internet_Explorer_11,Internet_Explorer_10,Internet_Explorer_9,Latest_Opera";}
```

I'm trying to retrieve records with a value containing **Bootstrap_3.x**

I've been able to retrieve the details field data based on the key: bootstrap with the following:

```
SELECT details as bootstrap_version FROM product_info WHERE details LIKE '%bootstrap%'
```

This query returns all records that have a field called bootstrap.

**What do I need to change in order to select values that contain Bootstrap_3.x?**

Any help would be appreciated.

hanks,
-Paul

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use regular expressions in your queries:

```
SELECT details as bootstrap_version FROM product_info
WHERE details REGEXP 'bootstrap";s:\\d+:"Bootstrap_3\.x'
```

However, if this information is something that you plan on using for search more often, I would suggest putting it in another column that you can index - regexp in queries are very slow.

Read more in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

You should user REGEXP:

```
SELECT details AS bootstrap_version FROM product_info WHERE details REGEXP 'Boostrap_3(\\.[0-9]+)+'
```